# Error in unique combination of keys in anova test

Tags: r, anova

I am currently doing a repeated measure anova test and can't get over that one error message saying:

```
Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 2 rows:
* 82, 83
```

This is the formula I used:

```
res.aov <- anova_test(data = data1, 
                      dv = AUC, wid = Observation,
                      within = c(SMIP, SMIB))
```

This is my data frame:

```
'data.frame':   410 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ ID                 : Factor w/ 125 levels "1","4","6","7",..: 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Observation        : Factor w/ 11 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 1 2 3 1 1 2 3 4 ...
 $ IDobs              : Factor w/ 407 levels "1.1","1.2","4.1",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ SMIP               : num  2.26 2.26 1.05 1.05 1.05 1.11 1.23 1.23 1.23 1.23 ...
 $ SMIB               : num  4.84 4.84 1.95 1.95 1.95 4.78 4.34 4.34 4.34 4.34 ...
 $ AUC                : num  21.2 16.6 19.2 16.9 18.5 15.4 10.4 12.8 15.4 17.9 ...
```

My df has different IDs (patient 1, 4, 6) with several observations (obs. 1, 2, for patient 1) for each one and therefor I have no idantical keys, even though they can have the same values in other variables (AUC). BUT - not every patient has the same number of observations! They vary from 1 - 11.
As you can see I tried combining the colums ID and Observation, but this didn`t help.
I tried removing the error lines in my excel sheet which led to the same error message but with different lines.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly apprecieated.
Many thanks in advance!
Nigina